# How to Rout ( react v3 ) when the component is imported is also route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am dealing it a problem and seems that I missing something.

I have the main Rout that contains an import **component** that also have routing

I am trying to rout inside the import component.

If I write localhost:9010/**testPath**
so I am getting to **ComponentThatImport** and that ok.

But I am trying to localhost:9010/**testPath/subPath**

and I get nothing, it actually renders the same localhost:9010/**testPath**

main rout

```
  const App = () => (
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <Router history={ syncedHistory }>
      <Route component={ Root }>
        <Route path={ '/testPath' }>
          <IndexRoute component={ ComponentThatImport }/>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

Component That Import from npm install

```
    const ComponentThatImport = () => (
      <Router>
         <div>
            <div>main ComponentThatImport</div>
            <Route path={ '/subPath' } component={ someComonnet }>
         </div>
      </Router>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ComponentThatImport need contain the `children` like

```
const ComponentThatImport = ({children}) => (
   <div>
      <div>main ComponentThatImport</div>
      {children}
   </div>
);

const SubComponentThatImport = () => (
   <div>
      <div>sub ComponentThatImport</div>
   </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
        <Route path="testPath" component={ComponentThatImport}>
          <Route path="subPath" component={SubComponentThatImport}/>
        </Route> 
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

The Example: https://codepen.io/v123582/pen/MZpWOd

Answer (score 0):

In react-router v3, routes are not defined in the nested components, rather they are defined as children of the `Route` component. Also you only need to have a Single `Router` instance as a provider

```
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <Router history={ syncedHistory }>
      <Route path="/" component={ Root }>
        <Route path={ 'testPath' } component={ComponentThatImport}>
          <Route path="subPath" component={SubComponentThatImport}/>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

---

```
const ComponentThatImport = ({children}) => (
     <div>
        <div>main ComponentThatImport</div>
        {children}
     </div>
);
```

[Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9y2wo5zjnr)